# Finding the parent of a node in a binary tree using a recursive function

Tags: c, binary-tree, parent

I know this one has been asked many times before but I could not find an answer that solves the problem in my implementation. The struct I'm using:

```
typedef struct STnode* link;
typedef struct STnode {Item item; link l, r; int N;}STnode;
link NULLnode;
```

Insertion functions:

```
link NEW(Item item, link l, link r, int N)
{
    link x = malloc(sizeof *x);
    x->item = item;
    x->l = l;
    x->r = r; 
    x->N = N;
    return x;
}

void InsertLeft (link node, Item item)
{
    node->l = NEW (item, NULLnode, NULLnode, 1); 
}

void InsertRight(link node, Item item)
{
    node->r = NEW(item, NULLnode, NULLnode, 1);
}

void BTinsertR (link node, Item item)
{
    InsertRight(node, item);
}

void BTinsertL (link node, Item item)
{
    InsertLeft(node, item);
}
```

Finally the problem function that I have been banging my head against for hours. It's supposed to return the item of the parent of the given node.

```
Item Parent(link root, link node)
{
    Item temp;
    if (root==node)
    {
        printf("The given node is root of a tree and thus has no parent\n");
        return NULLitem;
    }
    else if(root == NULLnode)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    else if(root->l==node || root->r==node)
    {
        temp = root->item;
        printf("Item of parent's node: %d\n", temp);
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        Parent(root->l, node);
        Parent(root->r, node);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Instead it prints the right item but returns the item of the last node I insert. The only time I alter the value of *temp* is when I find the node, so how is it possible that it changes at the last call?

EDIT: Forgot to add, my items are simple integers and the main function is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Item item = ITEMscan();
    NULLmaker();
    link root1 = MakeTree(item);
    item = ITEMscan();
    link root2 = MakeTree(item);
    item = ITEMscan();
    BTinsertL(root1, item);
    item = ITEMscan();
    BTinsertR(root1, item);
    item = ITEMscan();
    BTinsertL(root1->l, item);
    item = ITEMscan();
    BTinsertR(root1->l, item);
    item = ITEMscan();
    BTinsertL((root1->l)->l, item);
    Parent(root1, (root1->l)->l);
    return 0;
}
```

MakeTree simply initializes the tree

Comment: I recommend having `Parent` return a `link`, not an `Item`. Let the caller figure out what to do with the `link`. Returning the `link`'s `Item` seems unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: Sadly it's homework and It is specifically asked that it returns the item

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are two branches in `Parent` where `return temp;` will return an indeterminate value, since `temp` is never initialized. This would appear to be [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), but you should post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the definition of `Item`, and the code that drives these functions (`main`, etc.) if you want a concrete answer. Give us something that compiles.

Comment: I did change the returns so that no undefined behaviour occurs but results are the same, main function edited in!

Comment: Is there any reason to provide 2 `NULL` nodes to `NEW` function? Why not drop these parameters. It is also considered bad practice to hide pointer types in typedefs like the one for `link`. And what is purpose of `NULLnode` and I assume there is a `NULLitem`? If you want `NULL`, use `NULL`. Inventing funny names only confuses readers (that also includes your future self) without any benefit